# windows authentication continuously prompts username password for ie

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, active-directory, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I am developing an application which will be used in intranet.
I am using Windows authentication for the application with Active Directory.
But when i access the application from other machine in ie, it  continuously prompts for username and password.
I have added the settings in web.config for windows authentication, identity impersonation.
And IIS settings for application only windows authentication is enabled. anonymous authentication is disabled.
My observation is that it works fine for IIS 6.
But when i try to host my application on IIS 7.5 it continuously prompts username and password.
Also it does not work for Google Crome.

What can be the issue??? please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using ASP.NET Forms authentication and IIS Windows authentication in the same application**

You have a login.aspx page which allows your users to log in using Forms authentication.  But, all of your users also have Windows accounts on the server (or Active Directory). For some reason, you want all users to first log in using their Windows credentials, and then log in using their Membership credentials and Forms authentication.  You could do that by enabling Windows authentication and disabling Anonymous authentication in IIS, which would cause the request to be rejected by IIS before it would arrive in ASP.NET, thereby making sure that your users were first authenticated by Windows auth.

This works on IIS 6.0 and on IIS 7.0 in Classic mode. But, in Integrated mode, both Windows and Forms authentication run during the single stage authentication process, which makes it impossible to first authenticate with Windows authentication, and second authenticate with Forms authentication. Additionally, because Forms authentication is enabled for the entire application, there is no way to enable it for a part of your app and not for another – which presents a problem, because Forms authentication’s 302 redirect challenge is incompatible with the 401 “WWW-Authenticate” challenge used by Windows authentication.  Forms auth will always convert unauthorized requests to the application to a 302 redirect, thereby breaking Windows authentication.

for more details see [this link.](http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication)